# i am not receving the mail

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

```
$to = 'someone.com';
$firstname = $_POST["fname"];
$lastname = $_POST["fname"];
$subject= $_POST["subject"];
$email= $_POST["email"];
$text= $_POST["message"];



$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: " . $email . "\r\n"; // Sender's E-mail
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

this is my code for my php page. can you let me know what is wrong with my code. thank you for your help

```
if (mail($to,$subject,$text,$headers))
{
  echo "Check Email please";
}
 else
{
    echo 'failed';
}
```

Comment: Is there anything written to a log file? What makes you think that `someone.com` is a valid recipient?

Comment: Have you checked the Junk folder?

Comment: someone.com is just an example. i put my real mail in there

Comment: yes i check the junk folder but there was nothing

Comment: @NicoHaase what do you mean by log file?

Comment: If you run this code in your localhost,sure won't send the email as you don't have a real mail service.you should test this code in real server not your localhost.

Comment: ok thank you i will try it

Comment: you are welcome:search in google (free php host) and test your code,it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please make sure you are adding Phpmailer classes on the top.**

This is a proper working mailer file, put your credentials here and send the email.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Php Mailer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
        <?php 
    // require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

        require("PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php");
        require("PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php");
        require("PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php");


        $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
        $SendMailTo = "jonipk28@gmail.com";

        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                       

        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com;';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = "your_user_name_or_email@gmail.com";                 // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = "your_user_Password";                           // SMTP password
        // $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

        $mail->setFrom("your_user_name_or_email@gmail.com");
        $mail->addAddress($SendMailTo);     // Add a recipient             // Name is optional
        $mail->addReplyTo("your_user_name_or_email@gmail.com");

        // $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
        // $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

        ///send custom code in email
        $code = 242343;
        $mail->Subject = 'TeachMe verification email';
        $mail->Body    = 'Hi <br><br> <b>Thanks for registeration,Your verification code is </b>'.$code;
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo 'Message could not be sent.';
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            echo 'Message has been sent';
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```